# jQuery UI sortable - how to make some action with just moved item

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 lists with items, I add UI sortable to it.
How can I select and do some fun with just moved element?
When I'm trying this code - it add a class to all elements from first UL, but I need to add this class to just moved element to second UL.

```
<ul class="moveMe" id="ul1">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
<ul class="moveMe" id="ul2">
    <li></li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(".moveMe").sortable({
        connectWith: ".moveMe",
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $('li', this).addClass('justMoved');

        }
    }).disableSelection();
</script>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ui.item` instead of `this`.

```
$(".moveMe").sortable({
     connectWith: ".moveMe",
     stop: function (event, ui) {
         ui.item.addClass('justMoved');

     }
}).disableSelection();
```

See this <kbd>[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/5sxnz/)</kbd>

And the corresponding doc [entry](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop).

> **ui**
>
> **item**
>
> Type: jQuery
>
> The jQuery object representing the current dragged element